# smbpasswd command not found on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: command-line, passwords, samba, active-directory, ldap

I need to change my Active Directory password at my office, we have documentation on linux to use `smbpasswd` command line. On Debian, this command can be found in [`samba-common-bin`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/samba-common-bin). I wish I could switch my password from MacOS but I can't find `smbpasswd` command.

Answer (score 5):

Active Directory uses Kerberos for all authentication and supports the password-change protocol, so you should be able to directly use `kpasswd user@REALM` instead.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, I found I could just run on linux, inside docker! I found [dperson/samba](https://github.com/dperson/samba) which contains the compiled `smbpasswd` command. No need to try to setup samba on MacOS anymore ;)

```bash
docker run --rm -it dperson/samba \
bash -c "smbpasswd -U my_activedirectory_username -r 10.x.y.z"
```

Or if you like doing things on your own like I did, here's a debian `Dockerfile` which installs `samba-common-bin`:

```docker
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  samba-common-bin
```

Then you can build and run that docker file

```bash
docker build . -t example/debian-samba-common-bin
docker run --rm -it example/debian-samba-common-bin \
bash -c "smbpasswd -U my_activedirectory_username -r 10.x.y.z"
```

I published the above to [github.com/GabLeRoux/docker-debian-samba-common-bin](https://github.com/GabLeRoux/docker-debian-samba-common-bin), so you can do this:

```bash
docker run --rm -it gableroux/debian-samba-common-bin \
  bash -c "smbpasswd -U my_activedirectory_username -r 10.x.y.z"
```